# How should I organise my files according to PSR-0?

Tags: php, psr-0

I'm a bit confused with the guidelines and how to name the files.

1.) What does `Vendor` mean in `\<Vendor Name>\(<Namespace>\)*<Class Name>`

2.) If I name the namespace `AnimalsApp` and have an `abstract class Dog`, do I put concrete classes such as `GermanShepherd` in their own folder?

ie. `AnimalsApp\Dog\GermanShepherd\GermanShepherd.php` or `AnimalsApp\Dog\GermanShepherd.php`?

Further, do I include `Dog.php` in the `GermanShepherd.php` file, or is that up to the autoloader to load everything for me?

3.) Do all subclasses of the namespace need to have the namespace at the top of each file?

4.) Is `<Class Name>` synonymous to `<Interface>` here? What about when you have something like `class MyClass extends MyAbstract implements MyInterface`. Where do you put the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does Vendor mean in `\<Vendor Name>\(<Namespace>\)*<Class Name>`

Nothing in particular. Its importance is that all the other parts of the relative path are fully specified by the source code, and therefore "somewhat outside your control". The vendor prefix is there to allow you to have a class `Vendor1\Animals\Dog` and me to have a class `Vendor2\Animals\Dog` and for those two classes to not conflict if they ever happen to be used in the same application.

In practice: choose something that identifies yourself or your organization. It can be whatever you like, but since the idea is "something extremely unlikely to be picked by anyone else" decide accordingly.

> If I name the namespace AnimalsApp and have an abstract class Dog, do I put concrete classes such as GermanShepherd in their own folder?

You put concrete classes where their namespace dictates. If the fully qualified class name is `AnimalsApp\Dog\GermanShepherd` then you put it inside the directory `AnimalsApp\Dog`. If the FQCN is `AnimalsApp\GermanShepherd` then you put it inside `AnimalsApp`.

I should mention that both of the above examples seem unlikely and/or indicative of bad choices; the FQCN should *probably* be something like `AnimalsApp\Animals\GermanShepherd`.

> Further, do I include Dog.php in the GermanShepherd.php file, or is that up to the autoloader to load everything for me?

It's up to the autoloader.

> Do all subclasses of the namespace need to have the namespace at the top of each file?

A namespace does not *have subclasses*, it *contains classes*. Assuming that's what you meant then the answer is yes, because if the namespace is not there then by definition the classes are not contained inside it.

> Is `<Class Name>` synonymous to `<Interface>` here? What about when you have something like class MyClass extends MyAbstract implements MyInterface. Where do you put the files?

Treat interfaces and classes in the exact same way.

Comment: "I should mention that both of the above examples seem unlikely and/or indicative of bad choice."

Can you explain why this is? I mean, the GermanShepherd can only be a subset of the Dog class, right?

Comment: @tgun926: Whether `GermanShepherd` derives or does not derive from `Dog` is irrelevant. What matters is which namespace it is declared in. Since `Dog` is most likely the name of a class and *not* that of a namespace, it will never appear as a directory name.

Comment: Cheers! Just a bit of clarification with the vendor prefix - if it's job is to not cause conflicts if used in the same application, doesn't it have exactly the same job as namespaces?

Comment: @tgun926: Its job is to prevent conflicts between classes written by different people. If you are writing an application that will never for any reason include code written by anyone other than you the vendor prefix offers nothing because you can arrange for all class names to be different anyway.